# GeoDjango: Find all points within radius?

Tags: postgis, geodjango

I am working in GeoDjango (with a Django 1.7 and PostGIS 2.1.4 backend). I have a model with a PointField in my database and I am trying to find all items within 10km radius of a point.

Here is my model code:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    location = models.PointField(null=True, blank=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

Here is my view code (abridged for readability):

```
    from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
    from django.contrib.gis.measure import Distance
    lat = 52.5
    lng = 1.0
    radius = 10
    point = Point(lng, lat)
    print point
    places = Place.objects.filter(location__dwithin=(point.location, Distance(km=radius)))
```

This gives me:

```
AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute 'location'
```

I see the point in the console: `POINT (1.0000000000000000 52.5000000000000000)`.

How should I structure the query differently?

If I try just using `point` rather than `point.location` (as per [the dwithin documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#dwithin)) then I get a different error: `ValueError: Only numeric values of degree units are allowed on geographic DWithin queries`.

**UPDATE:**

This seems to work, but I don't know if it's correct:

```
    radius = int(radius)
    degrees = radius / 111.325
    point = Point(float(lng), float(lat))
    places = Place.objects.filter(location__dwithin=(point, degrees))
```

The results look OK, but I don't know if my conversion to degrees is reasonable.

Comment: No it is not, this ratio only works for equator.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.contrib.gis.measure import Distance  


lat = 52.5
lng = 1.0
radius = 10
point = Point(lng, lat)    
Place.objects.filter(location__distance_lt=(point, Distance(km=radius)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without GeoDjango if someone is interested, you just need 2 extensions on postgres: cube, earthdistance

```
from django.db.models import Lookup, Field, fields, Func, QuerySet


class LLToEarth(Func):
    function = 'll_to_earth'
    arg_joiner = ', '
    arity = 2  # The number of arguments the function accepts.

    def __init__(self, *expressions, output_field=None, **extra):
        if output_field is None:
            output_field = fields.Field()
        super().__init__(*expressions, output_field=output_field, **extra)


class EarthBox(LLToEarth):
    function = 'earth_box'
    arg_joiner = ', '


@Field.register_lookup
class Near(Lookup):
    lookup_name = 'in_georange'
    operator = '@>'

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        params = lhs_params + rhs_params
        return '%s @> %s' % (lhs, rhs), params


def filter_in_range(
        queryset: QuerySet,
        latitude: float,
        longitude: float,
        range_in_meters: int,
        latitude_column_name: str='latitude',
        longitude_column_name: str='longitude',
        field_name: str = 'earthbox',
        lookup_exp: str = 'in_georange',
):
    earthbox = {field_name: EarthBox(LLToEarth(latitude, longitude), range_in_meters)}
    lookup = '%s__%s' % (field_name, lookup_exp)
    in_range = {lookup: LLToEarth(latitude_column_name, longitude_column_name)}
    return queryset.annotate(**earthbox).filter(**in_range)
```